# Merging mp4 files with mp4parser

Tags: java, mp4parser

I need to merge 2 videos together both are mp4 and all other parameters are the same. The problem is when i have a big size file I cannot merge it i get a null pointer exception.
Here is the part were I think I went wrong but can't figure out the problem.

```
if (videoTracks.size() > 0) {
        result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(videoTracks.toArray(new Track[videoTracks.size()])));
    }

    if (audioTracks.size() > 0) {
        result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(audioTracks.toArray(new Track[audioTracks.size()])));
    }

    //Output the resulting movie to a new mp4 file
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String outputLocation = mediaStorageDir.getPath();
    Container out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(result);
```

error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.googlecode.mp4parser.boxes.mp4.ESDescriptorBox.getContentSize(ESDescriptorBox.java:60)
>       at com.googlecode.mp4parser.AbstractBox.getSize(AbstractBox.java:203)
>       at com.googlecode.mp4parser.BasicContainer.getContainerSize(BasicContainer.java:70)
>       at com.coremedia.iso.boxes.sampleentry.AudioSampleEntry.getSize(AudioSampleEntry.java:330)
>       at com.googlecode.mp4parser.BasicContainer.getContainerSize(BasicContainer.java:70)
>       at com.coremedia.iso.boxes.SampleDescriptionBox.getSize(SampleDescriptionBox.java:112)
>       at com.googlecode.mp4parser.AbstractContainerBox.getHeader(AbstractContainerBox.java:67)
>       at com.coremedia.iso.boxes.SampleDescriptionBox.getBox(SampleDescriptionBox.java:94)
>       at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.AppendTrack.mergeStsds(AppendTrack.java:81)
>       at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.AppendTrack.(AppendTrack.java:65)
>       at Mp4.merging.merge(merging.java:90)
>       at gui.maingui.projectionRecStopBActionPerformed(maingui.java:1281)
>       at gui.maingui.access$2000(maingui.java:60)
>       at gui.maingui$18.actionPerformed(maingui.java:941)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

can someone help me please!

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: I'll edit my post and add the error